# Reference file in Google drive in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api, google-drive-api

I have created a folder in Google Drive, e.g. test, and put 3 files inside it

```
a.jpg, b.jpg, c.jpg
```

I want in my Google Spreadsheet under the same account, to access the files, e.g. generate the link to image file,  is it possible?

e.g.

```
 ColA     ColB
 a.jpg    [generate link to a.jpg in drive]
 a.jpg    [generate  link to b.jpg in drive]
 a.jpg    [generate  link to c.jpg in drive]
```

Comment: Use:  imgur.com/dropbox ? - I had a quick look and there does not look to be an option for what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Yes its possible. Google for 'host website on google drive' for detailed instructions.
Basically first share the folder as public, copy the folder id from its url and make a new url googledrive.com/host/folderid/a.jpg

Answer (score 2):

With GScripts you can use the following functions to create/modify the files:

This one creates a new Spreadsheet with all Folder names and all corresponding URLS (no header)

```
function mapAllFiles() { 
  var values = [];
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("FOLDER_NAME");
  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    var files = folder.getFiles();
    // Looping over all files in all folders with the given name
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      Logger.log(file.getName());
      var fileInfo = [file.getName(), file.getDownloadUrl()];
      Logger.log(fileInfo);
      values.push(fileInfo);
      // values.push(file.getDownloadUrl());
    }
  }
  // To use an exiting spreadsheet
  // var sFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName("YOUR_SPREADSHEET_NAME");
  // var as = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sFile.next().getId());
  // Create a new spreadsheet
  var as = SpreadsheetApp.create("YOUR_SPREADSHEET_NAME");
  var sheet = as.getActiveSheet();
  // Fill in all values
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, 2).setValues(values);
}
```

This one list the URLs for the given fileNames in the spreadsheet which are present in the folder

```
function mapListedFiles() { 
  var values = [];
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("FOLDER_NAME");

  if (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();

    var sFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName("YOUR_SPREADSHEET_NAME");
    var as = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sFile.next().getId());
    // var as = SpreadsheetApp.create("YOUR_SPREADSHEET_NAME");
    var sheet = as.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getDataRange().getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < range.length-1; i++) {
      var files = folder.getFilesByName(range[i]);
      Logger.log(files);
      if (files.hasNext()) {
         var file = files.next();
         Logger.log(file.getName());
         Logger.log(file.getDownloadUrl());
        values.push([file.getDownloadUrl()]);
      } else {
        values.push(["MISSING"]);
      }
    }
    var range = sheet.getRange(2, 2, values.length, 1).setValues(values);
  }
}
```

Comment: I used the MapAllFiles function and it 'worked' producing a spreadsheet of file names and URLs but the download URLs did not work - just gave a blank browser window with no messages.

I made a simple change to use getId() instead to return the file id and prefixing the filed id with https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id= produced a working download URL

Answer (score 1):

Here is a principal way to do it (without programming). Later on you can automate this process in any way you wish.

1. **Using Google Drive API:** Go to Google Drive files API example (you may need to perform additional registration steps on Google Developers portal): https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list#try-it
2. **Filtering all files within a folder:** In "q" field put the string:

   `'0B6eKcFRCDRT2NjRGbDYxODlTMFE' in parents and trashed = False`

   where `0B6eKcFRCDRT2NjRGbDYxODlTMFE` is document ID of the folder where your images are located (you can view this identifier in URL when navigating to that folder in Google Drive web UI).
3. **Extracting fields you need:** In "fields" field put the string:

   `items(alternateLink,title)`
4. **Authentication:** Click "Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0" toggle in top-right, and allow access to your google drive
5. **Making API Request:** Click "Execute"
6. **Getting JSON-formatted response:** Scroll down, and copy the fragment of response following `"items":`, between square brackets (including them) for example:

   `[
     {
      "alternateLink": "https://...",
      "title": "Links to files"
     },
     {
      "alternateLink": "https://...",
      "title": "shanghai.jpg"
     },
     {
      "alternateLink": "https://...",
      "title": "map.JPG"
     },
     {
      "alternateLink": "https://...",
      "title": "London_2008.jpg"
     },
     {
      "alternateLink": "https://...",
      "title": "graph.png"
     },
     {
      "alternateLink": "https://...",
      "title": "chart_1.png"
     }
    ]`
7. **Converting JSON to CSV:** Paste this fragment to following web page: http://konklone.io/json/ - it will generate a table:

   [image]
8. **Using CSV as you need:** Copy this table and paste into your Google spreadsheet.