# add link to google sheet from folder name in drive

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am trying to find a way to add a new folder to google drive with name coming from the cell input in Column B in google sheets.

Or if easier add folder manually to drive and have script in google sheets add that folder name to a new row in google sheets column B.

Also either way i do it, i need the cell in column B to hyperlink to that new folder.

eg
Jobs Parent folder
job45846 job folder add link to this folder into cell in google sheets
job45893 job folder add link to this folder into new row cell in google sheets

Comment: IMHO, your second option is easier. You may want to check this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164515/reference-file-in-google-drive-in-google-spreadsheet) wherein it was stated that you just have to share [created folder](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder#creating_a_folder) as public, copy the folder id from its URL and make a new url `googledrive.com/host/folderid/a.jpg`. 

Sample code which creates a new Spreadsheet with all Folder names and all corresponding URLS was also given.

Comment: Thanks Teyam i had found that before i posted but that script lists the files inside a folder with a link in the column next to the filename. I need the folders to be listed with the link clickable to the drive folder on the folder name in the same column. i will have a bit more of a play around with the script see if i can get it working.

Answer (score 0):

```
function createAndHyperlink() {
var ss, sh, parent, r, v, thisCell, folder
ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
parent = DriveApp.getFolderById('folderid');
r = sh.getRange('A1:A')
v = r.getValues()
for (var i = 0, l = v.length; i < l; i++) {
    thisCell = sh.getRange(i + 1, 1)
    if (v[i][0] && !thisCell.getFormula()) {
        folder = parent.createFolder(v[i][0]);
        thisCell.setFormula('=HYPERLINK("' + folder.getUrl() + '"; "' + v[i][0] + '")');
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I have edited this a bit works by using column A values as folder name then create new folder in folder id given in the code as well as make the text a hyperlink to that new folder.